# Access violation on clearing qt scene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I have a class which contains a `QGraphicsScene`. In some function I wish to "clear" this scene from all items (& then fill it up with new items).

I tried the following code, but that gave me an access violation:

```
NewScene->clear();
```

NewScene is defined as following:

```
private:
    std::unique_ptr<QGraphicsScene> NewScene;
```

What goes wrong, and how can I clear this scene?

Comment: Have you allocated memory for `NewScene`? i.e. in ctor `NewScene(new QGraphicsScene)`?

Comment: @Naveen: ... Went through the constructors once again and found that I only allocated NewScene in the default constructor -.-. Solved now